# A Let f$:[-1,1] \to R, f'(0) =\lim_{n \to \infty} nf(\frac{1}{n})$ and $f(0)=0.$...

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

Problem :

A Let f$:[-1,1] \to R, f'(0) =\lim_{n \to \infty} nf(\frac{1}{n})$ and $f(0)=0.$ If $0<|\lim_{n \to \infty} cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n})|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{\pi}(n+1)cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n})-n=$

My approach :

$0 < cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{\pi}{2}$

$\Rightarrow 0 < (n+1) cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{\pi}{2}(n+1)$
$\Rightarrow 0 < \frac{2}{\pi} (n+1) cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{\pi}{2}(n+1) \frac{2}{\pi}$

$\Rightarrow -n < \frac{2}{\pi} (n+1) cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n})-n < 1$

Now putting the limits in the above

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} -n < \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2}{\pi} (n+1) cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{n})-n < \lim_{n \to \infty} 1$

please suggest how to work on this and whether this is correct method of approaching this. Thanks.

Comment: You question just have nothing to do with $f$??